# Generating random numbers inside while loop until desired number is generated

Tags: java, random, while-loop

One functionality of the program I am writing requires me to generate random numbers. However about 50% of these numbers won't be valid(which numbers are valid will be dependent on previous parts of my code) so my initial idea was to generate random numbers inside a while-loop until proper number is generated.

However, I am thinking if it is a good practice. Theoretically I should get the proper number within just a few repetitions(there is only 0,5^10 = 0,1% chance that the program will fail to do that within 10 repetitions) however it is still binding my program's performance to random number. So is it a bad practice despite probabilities being mostly insignificant?

There are work-around's that problem that doesn't require me to use loops but they would make that part of my code much more confusing. Someone could call them "over-engineering". Instead of having 4 lines of code to generate and check random number I would need 30-40 lines and declaring some new variables(probably arrays) to keep track of valid and invalid values. It seems easier to just generate a number and check if it's valid.

EDIT:
The code isn't written yet. I am on the stage of planning but for the sake of clarity I wrote the piece of code depicting what exactly my issue is. I also added some commentary. The code has no troubles with performance whenever I tried it and loops aren't repeated often but my exact question is: IS IT A BAD PRACTICE as there is no 100% sure way out of the loop and could potentially infinitely repeat itself(if we are very very unlucky)

```
public class App {
public static void main( String[] args ) {

    //creating a matrix that will have three horizontal or vertical "walls" of the length 5.
    int[][] matrix = new int[10][10];

    Random randomer = new Random();

    //loop will repeat 3 times creating new wall for each repetition
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        //for 0 wall horizontal, for 1 wall vertical
        int direction = randomer.nextInt(2);

        while (true) {

            // generating position of the first block of the wall. Wall cannot exceed matrix so one number shorter
            int axis1 = randomer.nextInt(10);
            int axis2 = randomer.nextInt(5);

            //walls cannot cross other wall so condition will check if all 5 fields are empty
            //for horizontal
            if (direction == 0 && matrix[axis2][axis1] == 0 && matrix[axis2 + 1][axis1] == 0
                    && matrix[axis2 + 2][axis1] == 0 && matrix[axis2 + 3][axis1] == 0
                    && matrix[axis2 + 4][axis1] == 0) {

                matrix[axis2][axis1] = 1;
                matrix[axis2 + 1][axis1] = 1;
                matrix[axis2 + 2][axis1] = 1;
                matrix[axis2 + 3][axis1] = 1;
                matrix[axis2 + 4][axis1] = 1;
                break;

            //for vertical
            } else if (matrix[axis1][axis2] == 0 && matrix[axis1][axis2 + 1] == 0
                    && matrix[axis1][axis2 + 2] == 0 && matrix[axis1][axis2 + 3] == 0
                    && matrix[axis1][axis2 + 4] == 0) {

                matrix[axis1][axis2] = 1;
                matrix[axis1][axis2 + 1] = 1;
                matrix[axis1][axis2 + 2] = 1;
                matrix[axis1][axis2 + 3] = 1;
                matrix[axis1][axis2 + 4] = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    //String visualisation of the matrix
    String textualMatrix = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            textualMatrix = textualMatrix + matrix[i][k] + "  ";
        }
        textualMatrix = textualMatrix + "\n";
    }
    System.out.println(textualMatrix);
}
}
```

One example of output:

```
0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  0
```

The empty fields are represented by 0 and 3 walls are represented by 1's.

So to repeat my question: **Is there any principle of good coding practices that should prevent me from such a solution?** I want the code to not only work but also be a quality code.

***QUICK ANSWER:*** Thanks everyone for help! So as farest I understood from your answers: this is not a bad practice! However in some cases(like life saving apps or bigger performance burden) keeping track of valid values instead of randomly generating at the cost of the code simplicity is justified and could be a better solution. Cases should be evaluated individually.

Comment: personally I would just use the loop variant. Unless of course the code is [*hot*](https://www.hackterms.com/hot%20code). Then you may want to rethink your approach, i.e. using a custom made [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) which only outputs valid values defined by your earlier code.

Comment: 50% is a rather decent acceptance rate for a rejection sampling algorithm.  Have you measured the performance of your program when it uses the random generation feature?  Is your program currently too slow because of the feature?  Can you explain more (or give code) on what the random generation feature does?

Comment: And note: *explaining* code in human language is always a suboptimal approach here. Always try to come up with the key pieces ... as code.

Comment: I added a code and further explanation in the original post. So far the code has no troubles with performance but my question is about good coding practices. Is such a solution a quality solution? The fact that loop break isn't predictable and is based on randomly generated numbers raised my concerns. But maybe that is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you would exclude the invalid possibilities before calling the random. Eventually one random call over the two axis (-> 10x10 possiblities) minus the invalid ones.

But if this becomes over-complicated, I consider your approach as ok, no bad practice. How critical is your mission? For examples, if human lifes are concerned, that would be too much risks. If it is for a game or a shop, something the user can re-try, it is sufficient.

Do you really want this endless loop? Perhaps limit to 100 or 1000 times. If over, log and abort. Then monitor your log, if possible. You can then re-consider your algorithm if the error rate goes up (perhaps if walls get longer or matrix get smaller, you would have more invalid combinations).

Answer (score 0):

The indeterminate performance caused by the random number generation is a theoretical problem.  Depending on the scope of the numbers, you are not going to make more than a couple of attempts before you find an allowed value and each attempt is quick, in and of itself.  But let's say it takes 1000 attempts to find an allowed coordinate - is that even perceptible to the end user?

Nonetheless, an alternate approach would be to maintain a List containing the allowed Coordinates within the matrix.  Randomly select from that List and you are guaranteed to get an allowed value.  This adds complexity because you have to maintain that List.  That complexity may not be warranted - see first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I remember from University that such a technique can be used to easily model weird distribution. It's called 'Rejection Sampling'.

For example, if you want a number between 0 and 100, uniformly distributed except for e.g. 42, which should occur 10% less than any other number.

Then you would have an algorithm like this:

```
while true:
  result = random.nextInt(100)
  if result != 42:
    return result
  else:
    // 42 is skipped in 10% of cases
    if random.nextInt(10) != 9:
      return result
    else:
      // do nothing, go back through the while true loop
```

So it's a valid technique, at least in academics.

For a more complex example, see this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUL0TOLYNLE

But in this case, there's only a 0.1 % of actually needing a repeat, and 0.0001 % change of needing 2 repeats.

But on modern systems, having a 50% chance of getting repeats, and limiting it at a 1000 repeats or so is probably not too bad.

Answer (score 0):

Given you are creating 3 walls of length 5 in a 10x10 space then you'll always have a location to place a valid wall. So your approach will work fine.

If you change the number of walls it is not clear when you can get impossible configurations.

At what if you change a length? I would recommend creating a method to check if a point is valid.

```
boolean isValidHorizontal( int[][] matrix, int x, int y, length ){
    int length = 5;
    if(y + length > matrix.length ){
        return false;
    }
    for(int j = 0; j<length; j++){
        if(matrix[y][x + j] != 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then you can filter you can filter all of the points.

```
int n = matrix.length * matrix[0].length;
List<int[]> hPoints = new ArrayList<>(n);
for(int i = 0; i<matrix.length; j++){
    for(int j = 0; j<matrix[0].length; j++){
        if( isValidHorizontal(matrix, i, j) ){
            hPoints.add(new int[]{i, j});
        }
    }
}
```

And return a random valid one.

```
if( hPoints.size() > 0){
    return hPoints.get( random.nextInt( hPoints.size() ) );
}
```

There is a trade off here. You have to scan everypoint and store it in a list. When you have a few lines, I would expect this to be slower than just randomly picking one. Once you have many lines, then this will be faster. Also, this lets you know if you have no possible choices.